# RegEx to create URL whitelist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Working on a script to target external site URL's and give class to trigger dialog. Need to exclude (White list) certain HREF. Exception for mailto and tel as well as internal URL's works fine but trying to add specific URL name doesn't work. Any suggestions? Is there a better method?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

$.expr[":"].external = function (a) {
    return !a.href.match(/^mailto\:/) && !a.href.match(/^tel\:/) && !a.href.match(/http\/\/\:\mail\.google\.com/) && a.hostname != location.hostname
};
$("a:external").addClass("ext_link");
```

});

Comment: Other than having your slashes and colons reversed, this seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/5bZVh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps

```
return !/^(mailto|tel):|http:\/\/mail\.google\.com/.test(a.href) &&
    a.hostname != location.hostname
```

Comment: Thanks MikeM! Really like the way this was streamlined! Running with this solution.